# JQuery Flot timestamps

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I'm trying to get timestamps in the format of m/d/y to display in my x-axis using `flot`.  I've read through the [API docs](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data), but the timestamps aren't converting still.  Where have I gone wrong?

[image: flot graph]

```
<!-- Flot demo info -->
    <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
            //random data
            var d1 = [
                [(new Date(2016, 6, 23)).getTime(), 55],
                [(new Date(2016, 6, 24)).getTime(), 45],
                [(new Date(2016, 6, 25)).getTime(), 55],
                [(new Date(2016, 6, 26)).getTime(), 65],
                [(new Date(2016, 6, 27)).getTime(), 25],
                [(new Date(2016, 6, 28)).getTime(), 85],
                [(new Date(2016, 6, 29)).getTime(), 15],
            ];

            //flot options
            var options = {
              series: {
                curvedLines: {
                  apply: true,
                  active: true,
                  monotonicFit: true
                }
              },
              colors: ["#26B99A"],
              grid: {
                borderWidth: {
                  top: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  bottom: 1,
                  left: 1
                },
                borderColor: {
                  bottom: "#7F8790",
                  left: "#7F8790"
                }
              }
            };
            var plot = $.plot($("#security_activity"), [{
              label: "Security",
              data: d1,
              yaxis: {},
              xaxis: {
                mode: "time",
                timeformat: "%m/%d/%y"
              },
              lines: {
                fillColor: "rgba(150, 202, 89, 0.12)"
              }, //#96CA59 rgba(150, 202, 89, 0.42)
              points: {
                fillColor: "#fff"
              }
            }], options);
          });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, stupid me... had the xaxis/yaxis options in the wrong spot.

Updated Code:

```
<!-- Flot demo info -->
    <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
            //random data
            var d1 = [
                [(new Date(2016, 6, 23)).getTime(), 55],
                [(new Date(2016, 6, 24)).getTime(), 45],
                [(new Date(2016, 6, 25)).getTime(), 55],
                [(new Date(2016, 6, 26)).getTime(), 65],
                [(new Date(2016, 6, 27)).getTime(), 25],
                [(new Date(2016, 6, 28)).getTime(), 85],
                [(new Date(2016, 6, 29)).getTime(), 15]
            ];

            //flot options
            var options = {
              series: {
                curvedLines: {
                  apply: true,
                  active: true,
                  monotonicFit: true
                }
              },
              colors: ["#26B99A"],
              grid: {
                borderWidth: {
                  top: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  bottom: 1,
                  left: 1
                },
                borderColor: {
                  bottom: "#7F8790",
                  left: "#7F8790"
                }
              },
              yaxis: {},
              xaxis: {
                mode: "time",
                timeformat: "%m/%d/%y",
                minTickSize: [1, "day"]
              }
            };
            var plot = $.plot($("#security_activity"), [{
              label: "Security",
              data: d1,
              lines: {
                fillColor: "rgba(150, 202, 89, 0.12)"
              }, //#96CA59 rgba(150, 202, 89, 0.42)
              points: {
                fillColor: "#fff"
              }
            }], options);
          });
        </script>
```